# NetBios issues with multiple adapters, may not be turning on

Tags: networking, windows-server-2008, ipv4, netbios

I'm working in a Windows 2008 server. I'm getting conflicting messages as to weather or not netbios is enabled. The problem is that my AD users **can't** "discover" the server. I think that netbios is to blame.

look at this screen shot. [image: settings]

obviously, I have the enable box checked. As I understand this the cli is telling me that its on, but the details are saying no. In practices it seems to be no.

Also, I tried, 
"C:\Users\administrator.CCC>nbtstat -n" 
I get NetBT is not bound to any devices"
How would I bind it?

The settings and issues are the same on both adapters. 
I'm not evens sure if netbios is functioning. 
I'm a bit out of my depth here, I greatly appreciate any advice.

Comment: Do you have Network Discovery enabled on the machine in question?

Comment: I have set it to on, but it seems not to be saving much like the netbios settings.

Answer (score 0):

Network discovery isn't the function or responsibility of a single component. While NetBIOS is one of those components, it isn't the only one. If you want to disable Network Discovery then you should do it from the advanced sharing settings in Network and Sharing center.